# Android: internet access connection

Tags: android, internet-connection

I'm retreiving data from an internet service.

Is there a way to control which (data) connection the device uses for connecting to a website?(access via wifi or via the cellular network)

Answer (score 4):

No.  This can't be done in the browser, nor in your own application.

However, in your application you could *detect* which data connectivity type is currently active, using the [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) class.